# Standard Chinese translation of "I'm not a bad person"

Tags: grammar, learning, adjectives, negation

I'm trying to translate "I'm not a bad person" to standard Chinese. I am told the following:

> There are also two ways to say "A **isn't** B". When **B** is a *noun* (things, people, places, etc.), use **bú shì**.

It seemed to me that **B** here is "bad", which is an adjective. So I said that the translation would be "wô bú huài-rén". The only other option would have been to add "shì".

But I was told that this is incorrect. It seems to me that I followed the information correctly, no? Did I do something incorrectly, or are the instructions incorrect?

Thank you.

Comment: The information is correct, 我是人 > 我不是人 > 我不是坏人.   我坏 > 我不坏. When you analyze sentences, you need to strip out all the modifiers, e.g. 我保证我以前真的不是一个特别好的人. -> 我是人 when you remove all the modifiers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**B** is *person*, which is a noun. So you should use 不是. *Bad* is an adjective and it's used to modify *person*, so the translation should be

```
我不是一个坏人。
```

Comment: If **A** is "I'm" and **B** is "person", then, using their reasoning, we would have "I'm not person", so I think their explanation is incorrect, no?

Comment: @ThePointer **A** is "I" and **B** is "person", then "I'm not person" should be translated as 我不是人. Where is the explanation incorrect?

Comment: I meant their explanation is incorrect. The point is to say that "I'm not bad", but if **B** is "person", then "A **isn't** B" becomes "I'm **isn't/not** person", right?

Comment: @ThePointer Yes. I think the theory is just talking about grammar struction, meaning is not considered. The point is there's "person" at the end of the sentence and it's a noun. If the sentence is just "I'm not bad", and "bad" is an adjective, then the translation would be 我不坏.